# TopicPartitionOffset does not work for SeekPosition.Timestamp

Tags: spring-kafka

When I want to retrieve data from Kafka it should be possible to do so from a certain timestamp. I was under the impression that this could be achieved by using **TopicPartitionOffset** with a 4th parameter **SeekPosition.Timestamp**. This, however does not work. When I pass a valid Instant (I know it is in the range of valid dates, i.e kafka has records with appropriate timestamps) the following console messages appear:

`Seeking to offset 1626779437 for partition secret-partition-0`

`Fetch offset 1626779437 is out of range for partition secret-partition-0, resetting offset.`

`Resetting offset for partition secret-partition-0 to offset 450108.`
The offset to which the reset takes place is the last offset on the topic. I checked this with a tool called offset explorer. So it is the same as using

`return new TopicPartitionOffset(topic, p, SeekPosition.END);`

This however is only used when there is no Instant passed, which works well.

What is the purpose of using TopicPartitionOffset with a timestamp when the timestamp is not calculated into the appropriate offset? Does the offset still need to be calculated manually by means of using a Consumer and its offsetsForTimes method?

Is there anything wrong with the code or is **TopicPartitionOffset** created wrong?
Please see attached code. Also note that "orElseGet" is only called when no Instant is passed, which for the current problem is not the case. The ".map" path is run correctly and produces a value.

```
listenerContainer = contentKafkaListenerContainerFactory.createContainer(
                partitions.stream()
                    .map(p ->
                        Optional.ofNullable(instant)
                                .map(i -> {
                                    return new TopicPartitionOffset(topic, p, i.getEpochSecond(), SeekPosition.TIMESTAMP);
                                })

                                .orElseGet(() -> {
                                    return new TopicPartitionOffset(topic, p, SeekPosition.BEGINNING);                  
                                })
                    )
                    .toArray(TopicPartitionOffset[]::new)
        );

        listenerContainer.setupMessageListener(kafkaMessageListener);
        listenerContainer.start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after same fiddling aroung it seems that this problem can be solved by the usage of the ConsumerSeekAware interface.
My code above is correct except the usage of

```
return new TopicPartitionOffset(topic, p, i.getEpochSecond(), SeekPosition.TIMESTAMP);
```

That should be:

```
return new TopicPartitionOffset(topic, p, i.toEpochMilli(), SeekPosition.TIMESTAMP);
```

It seems that creating a TopicPartitionOffset does not offset the partition when a partition is assigned but only serves as container for the offset, so a manual step is needed, where the actual offsetting is applied.

```
public class KafkaTopicOffsetter implements ConsumerSeekAware {
@Override
public void onPartitionsAssigned(Map<TopicPartition, Long> assignments, ConsumerSeekCallback callback) {
        assignments.forEach((topicPartition, aLong) -> {
                    callback.seekToTimestamp(topicPartition.topic(), topicPartition.partition(), aLong);
                }
        );
    }
}
```

This seems to do the trick if you use a ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory to create your listeners as done in my original question.

Kind regards

Comment: Thanks for reporting. Seek to timestamp was added later and wasn't added for manual assignment - I opened a new feature issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1876